# log4j & Apache Kafka - Disabling specific log output

Tags: java, apache-kafka, log4j

So, I'm supposed to disable a repated logger-warning from my works code.
As I'm not working on it primarily, I don't know the necessary function.

It's a KafkaClient Application, Initialising two Consumers. But in the case of working on it locally, which they / I do, it cannot connect to a broker.
That means org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient repeatedly logs two warnings each for each of the Consumers

```
Connection to node -1 (localhost: {IP}) could not be established. Broker
may not be available.

Bootstrap broker {ip} (id = -1 rack = null) disconnected.
```

I can easily pinpoint which two methods cause the logger to give this output.
Is there anyway, such as a config file, to supress this warning?
I haven't yet worked with loggers (IT Student), so all the solutions or tips I've found are just confusing to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried searching around the log4j documentation? And you'd disable on packages or classes, not methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try filtering WARN logs using the below snippet in log4j.xml

```
    <category name="org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient">
        <priority value="ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref=[your appender name]/>
    </category>
```

This will filter the WARN logs and will print only the ERROR logs.

Comment: I realized really late it was a spring based kafka, and my manipulation should go into the application.properties.  
logging.level.org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient = OFF / ERROR  
solved my problems.
But thank you for pointing me in the right direction.